# Running an asyncoio socket server and client on the same process for tests

Tags: sockets, pytest, python-asyncio

I wrote a socket server and client package with asyncio that happens to be a single module with two classes `Server` and `Client`. The intention is to have the code check if the specified port is in use on the same device, and if so, it will choose the use the `Client` class instead of the `Server` class. I am doing this to enable local testing between client and server for a larger goal.

I wrote my unit test with `pytest` and I can get it to pass if I run the server in its own process first, then run the client in another process.

However, I want to test both server and client together in the same process using pytest. The test never completes this way, however.

Am I running into an issue with asyncio here? Or is it an issue with pytest? Or is it something I am doing wrong in my code?

**WebSockets.websocket**

```py
import asyncio


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = None
        self.connections = {}

    async def start(self):
        self.server = server = await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, self.host, self.port)
        addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print(f'Serving on {addr}')
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
        print(f'New connection from {addr}')
        self.connections[addr] = writer
        try:
            while not reader.at_eof():
                data = await reader.read(100)
                message = data.decode()
                if message:
                    print(f'Received {message!r} from {addr}')
                    await self.send(message, addr)
        finally:
            del self.connections[addr]
            writer.close()

    async def send(self, message, addr):
        writer = self.connections.get(addr)
        if not writer:
            return
        writer.write(message.encode())
        await writer.drain()

    async def recv(self, addr):
        reader, _ = await asyncio.open_connection(addr[0], addr[1])
        data = await reader.read(100)
        return data.decode()

    async def stop(self):
        await self.server.close()


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.reader = None
        self.writer = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port)

    async def send(self, message):
        self.writer.write(message.encode())

    async def recv(self):
        data = await self.reader.read(100)
        return data.decode()

    async def close(self):
        self.writer.close()
```

**Test**

```py
import socket
import asyncio
from WebSockets.websocket import Server, Client
import pytest


def check_port(address, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((address, port))
        s.close()
        return "server"
    except OSError:
        return "client"


async def serve():
    server = Server('localhost', 8910)
    await server.start()


async def client_connect():
    client = Client('localhost', 8910)
    await client.connect()
    await client.send("Hello world!")

    message = await client.recv()
    if message:
        print(f"Received {message!r} from server")
        assert message == "Hello world!"
        await client.close()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_sockets():
    if check_port("localhost", 8910) == "server":
        await serve()
        # for reference on how to use in non pytest module
        # loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        # loop.run_until_complete(serve())
        # loop.close()
    else:
        await client_connect()
        # for reference on how to use in non pytest module
        # loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        # loop.run_until_complete(client_connect())
        # loop.close()
```

Comment: You also need event_loop fixture `@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
                                                          def event_loop():
                                                                  return asyncio.get_event_loop()`